# Ajax call don't receive html content from MVC Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my action:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult DesignItemsList(int dealId, string sort)
{
    return View(MVC.Designer.Views._DesignItems, _designerService.GetDesignItems(dealId, sort));
}
```

The `GetDesignItems()` method is working correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product__filtr__form__select').change(function(e) {
        var sort = $(this).val();
        var urlFilter = $('#url-filterPanel-hidden-field').val();
        var dealId = $('#dealId-hidden-field').val();
        var urlItems = $('#url-items-hidden-field').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                dealId: dealId,
                sort: sort
            },
            url: urlItems,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#Product-Items-Container').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Request is working too, but I don't receive the response and get only 500 code.

Answer (score 0):

500 error code means, Internal server error. Your action method failed to process thie request you sent.

Since it is a GET action method, You may add the query string parameters to the url.

```
 var sort = $(this).val();
 var dealId = $('#dealId-hidden-field').val();
 var urlItems = $('#url-items-hidden-field').val();

 urlItems = urlItems+"?dealId="+dealId+"&sort"+sort;

 //Let's write to console to verify the url is correct.
 console.log(urlItems);

 $.get(urlItems,function(res){

    console.log('result from server',res);
    $('#Product-Items-Container').html(res);

 });
```

Comment: did you try to access the url  (we wrote to console) in a browser tab and see what response you are getting. May be your server code is failing,

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the view name inside your controller:

```
return View("YourControllerView", _designerService.GetDesignItems(dealId, sort));
```

Because I was tested your ajax request and find out that it works fine.
And pay attention to view location. This view must be located inside the directory with the same name as your controller or inside the shared dictory